# Google spreadsheet on team drive not running script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a google form on my Team Drive that when submitted pulls that data to a spreadsheet.  I used a script within that spreadsheet that pulls the unique URL to that specific submitted form.  My team members are able to submit the form and access the spreadsheet for editing, however the script only runs for me.  All of my team members have full access to the drive.  I have scoured as far as I know how to resolve this issue but have only come to potential answers.  One of those answers was to publish the script as a web app or API executable.  This is a little out of my scope but would love to get this working for my team as it is extremely useful.  Not to mention I could relay this information to other projects if I can get it resolved.  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please be more specific. How does the script is called? Did you create a on form submit trigger? Try to reproduce the problem by creating a [mcve] and add to code to the question.

Comment: Is it possible that your using commands like SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet or getActiveSheet.  When your users are using the form there is no active spreadsheet.  So perhaps you should be using openById and getSheetByName().  Just a thought.

Comment: scripts and add-ons are not yet supported in team drives.

Comment: The script simply pulls the URL to edit the specific form to the spreadsheet.  There is a trigger that works on form submission.  It's nothing intricate, I found it on the web.  I had created a very simple test and had been unsuccessful so far.  Unfortunately, my time is also spent working help desk so I don't have too much time to invest in researching.  I just wanted to create a tool to better assist my team.  If Bjorn is correct about scripts and add-ons not being support, then I believe this is the simple answer.  I was leaning this way, but wondered if perhaps there was a workaround.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046012/no-such-user-when-trying-to-access-google-apps-script-editor/ , i think this solves your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Such User when trying to access google apps script editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046012/no-such-user-when-trying-to-access-google-apps-script-editor)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a script then publishing the script is not that difficult.  [See the link here to see how to do it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions) (See deploying a script as a web app: six simple steps!)
Also from the documentation: When a web app in a Team Drive is deployed, choosing to "execute as you" causes the web app to execute under the authority of the user that deployed it (since there is no script owner).