# No Such User when trying to access google apps script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my Google spreadsheet, when I go to "Tools->Script Editor..", I get a page saying "No Such User" Error. Any idea how to fix this?
I figure this could be a permissions issue, but not sure how to change permissions if required.

Comment: does that file belong to you and are you logged-in?

Comment: Yes im logged in, its in a team drive. Also when i click Share and then see "Who has Access", i do have Edit permissions, this was supposed to show who is the owner but the new UI doesn't show that. It was created by a team-mate who has now left the organisation.

Comment: oh so the owner of the file has been removed (coz he left)?

Comment: Perhaps you/admin of your GSuite domain should try to change the owner of Google Spreadsheet, as the previous owner's account might be deactivated.

Comment: Team Drive essentially removes the user because the file is shared between all users in the Drive. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766455/google-spreadsheet-on-team-drive-not-running-script) is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution accidentally.
The issue is resolved by enabling GoogleAppsScript as part of your drive.

Open Google Drive in your web browser.
Click New > More > + Connect more Apps
and then select GoogleAppsScript.

Once i did this going back to script editor of my spreadsheet, no more gives any error.

Here is the link which contained this step:- 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/apps-script

Also there is additional problem about Invalid OAuth Client when trying to run the script. which i faced since each apps script has to be attached to a Google Cloud Project. This is accessible only to the person who originally created the file even after its in the team drive. In which case, you need to make a copy of the apps script available by going into File->Make a copy. And then in the Resources drop down , you will see Cloud Platform Project, upon clicking it you can now give the project number of the Google Cloud Platform project you created on console.cloud.google.com.